# Ethernet connection issue on ubuntu 16.04 dell G7

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet, dell, ethernet

I am having issues connecting to the ethernet connection on ubuntu 16.05 on a dell G7 laptop computer. The computer connects to the wifi but does not show the ethernet connection. I have tested with several cables but the problem persists. The computer is new and I could not understand how to solve this problem. When connecting the ethernet button on the networking tab the wifi signal just flashes and the two arrow ethernet symbol never shows up. I am new to network setups so any help would be deeply appreciated. Thanks.

Here is the output of the ifconfig:

```
enp60s0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 3c:2c:30:f0:19:70  
          inet6 addr: fe80::a0c0:937b:37c7:3217/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:65 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:205 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:38350 (38.3 KB)  TX bytes:39852 (39.8 KB)
          Interrupt:17 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:20337193 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:20337193 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:347481658434 (347.4 GB)  TX bytes:347481658434 (347.4 GB)

wlp0s20f3 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 98:3b:8f:79:04:4b  
          inet addr:133.87.124.214  Bcast:133.87.124.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::69e7:ded4:333c:966c/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:176402 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:25187 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:62107377 (62.1 MB)  TX bytes:3804632 (3.8 MB)
```

and the output of lshw -C network is below:

```
arav@arav-G7:~$ lshw -C network 
    WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
      *-network               
           description: Wireless interface
           product: Wireless-AC 9560 [Jefferson Peak]
           vendor: Intel Corporation
           physical id: 14.3
           bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
           logical name: wlp0s20f3
           version: 10
           serial: 98:3b:8f:79:04:4b
           width: 64 bits
           clock: 33MHz
           capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
           configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.15.0-48-generic firmware=34.0.0 ip=133.87.124.214 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
           resources: irq:16 memory:ed41c000-ed41ffff
      *-network
           description: Ethernet interface
           product: Killer E2400 Gigabit Ethernet Controller
           vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
           physical id: 0
           bus info: pci@0000:3c:00.0
           logical name: enp60s0
           version: 10
           serial: 3c:2c:30:f0:19:70
           size: 100Mbit/s
           capacity: 1Gbit/s
           width: 64 bits
           clock: 33MHz
           capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
           configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=alx duplex=full latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
           resources: irq:17 memory:ed200000-ed23ffff ioport:3000(size=128)
    WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
```

And my /etc/network/interfaces files look like this :

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

#primary ethernet interface
auto enp60s0 
iface enp60s0  inet dhcp
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an IPv6 address. So I guess that you can get a connection by turning off Ipv6 and restart the interface.

1.Turning off IPv6

Please add

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1

net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1

net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

to

`/etc/sysctl.conf`

and then type the following command and press Enter on a command line

`sudo sysctl -p`

This should be enough to turn off IPv6 but there is some bug and therefore we need to write some script to turn off IPv6 automatically when we boot Ubuntu.

Please create a new file `/etc/rc.local` and add these contents

```
#!/bin/bash
# /etc/rc.local

# Load kernel variables from /etc/sysctl.d
/etc/init.d/procps restart

exit 0
```

and give the permission to execute to the file

```
chmod 755 /etc/rc.local
```

2.Restart the interface

```
ifdown enp60s0 && ifup enp60s0
```

Comment: Hi I am getting the following message after following your advice:`sudo ifdown enp60s0 && ifup enp60s0
ifdown: interface enp60s0 not configured
ifup: failed to open lockfile /run/network/ifstate.enp60s0: Permission denied`

Comment: Then please try `sudo ifup enp60s0` first.

Comment: `ifup: interface enp60s0 already configured`

Comment: OK, then `sudo ifdown enp60s0 && sudo ifup enp60s0`

Comment: tried it but no success

Comment: Show me the result of `sudo ifdown enp60s0 && sudo ifup enp60s0`